# Revert Ubuntu 22.04 Gnome to Default

Tags: 22.04

I accidentally removed Ubuntu Gui related apps using the autoremove command.
I reinstalled ubuntu-desktop and now, I think I have the upstream gnome version, because the settings no longer has the "Appearance" option, in short, reinstalling Gnome desktop gets me the GNOME 4 upstream version. Not Ubuntu's. I want to revert back to Ubuntu's gnome version where the panel is on the left side. Searching the internet is getting nowhere.
Now, I tried: `sudo apt install ubuntu-gnome-desktop` and `dconf reset` and restarted to no avail.

How do I get back Ubuntu 22.04's Gnome version?

Thank you,
Allan

Answer (score 7):

Found the solution.

When I accidentally remove ubuntu-gnome-desktop packages, I end up in the command line with no GUI. Then to get back the GUI, I installed the "gnome-desktop" upstream (unbeknownst to me) package and came with the gnome-shell which must be also the upstream version and not from Ubuntu. That's the reason I have the upstream Gnome desktop version. Reinstalling ubuntu-gnome-desktop at this point will not change anything because of the presence of upstream gnome-shell package.

To fix this:
Remove the ubuntu-desktop and gnome-shell packages.

```
apt purge gnome-shell
apt purge ubuntu-desktop
apt autoremove -y
apt install --reinstall ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

That will force the ubuntu-gnome-desktop to reconfigure everything back to default.

Reboot. That will fix this issue.

Thanks,
Allan